# Do voltDB or NuoDB need ElasticSearch?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, elasticsearch, full-text-indexing, voltdb

Currently I am working in a project that use PostgreSQL + ElasticSearch. However I recently found VoltDB, and I was wondering if we still need ElasticSearch for doing searches with VoltDB.

If I am ok, elasticSearch get the data from PostgreSQL of from another relational Database, and them it reindexes the data to make faster Queries instead using the relational Database indexes. This is because the data stored in ElasticSearch is not completely trusted because ElasticSearch is not ACID compliant.

Comment: Check out Crate.io? Maybe this will help solve your problem by combining your two problem spaces into one.

Comment: @Bigluis - did you find any feasible solution for this ? I am facing a similar issue at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my (limited) knowledge of ElasticSearch, it appears that it is a search server that would work in conjunction with the database and is used primarily to search and index document files.

If this is correct, I don't think that NuoDB would be a replacement for ElasticSearch but could likely work in conjunciton with it similar to PostgreSQL.

Also, similar to Volt, NuoDB doesn't have full-text-indexing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

VoltDB is very fast and is excellent at parallelizing work across hardware resources. It doesn't contain any kind of full-text-indexing functionality. Any kind of full-text search on VoltDB will be at least mostly brute force. That doesn't mean it won't meet your needs, but it really depends on the kind of queries you want to run.

Comment: so that, we need elasticsearch for Full-text Search and complex queries, right?